# I can't configure Tomcat webapp to be able debugged on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, web-applications

I've read a lot of post here and tutorials on internet but I'm not able to connect to my webapp on a Tomcat from my Eclipse to be able to debug my code.

Following some post and tutorials, I've modified the `catalina.bat` (I'm on Windows 7) to star on debug mode:

```
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
set MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
set ACTION=jpda start
set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=
set DEBUG_OPTS=
set JPDA=jpda
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
set JPDA_SUSPEND=n
set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%

if not ""%1"" == ""jpda"" goto noJpda
set JPDA=jpda
if not "%JPDA_TRANSPORT%" == "" goto gotJpdaTransport
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
:gotJpdaTransport
if not "%JPDA_ADDRESS%" == "" goto gotJpdaAddress
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
:gotJpdaAddress
if not "%JPDA_SUSPEND%" == "" goto gotJpdaSuspend
set JPDA_SUSPEND=n
:gotJpdaSuspend
if not "%JPDA_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJpdaOpts
set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
:gotJpdaOpts
shift
:noJpda
```

And also:

```
:doStart
shift
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat
set _EXECJAVA=jpda start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd
```

Then, on Eclipse I've created a server with the Tomcat instalation and selected "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of the Tomcat installation)":

[image]

And on the server I've set the variable "jpda":

[image]

Now, I've created a debug configuration, following the parameters specified on the `catalina.bat`:

[image]

But when I run the server from eclipse by pressing the button "Start the server in debug mode" and try to connect, I get this error:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck...

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Try running the server and then attach the debugger to it

Comment: I've tried it, run the server normal and attach the debugger and run the server in debug mode and attach the debugger but in both cases I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't really know what happened but I did on the server tab right click > Clean Tomcat Work Directory... and then I launched it on "Start the server in debug mode" and now works.

I leave the post for someone who may have the same issue, as he/she can see here all the steps by picture or code.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install Tomcat and plugins.

1. create a maven project with dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itranswarp.learnjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-embedded-hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.26</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2. Write a main() to start tomcat with current webapp:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.getInteger("port", 8080));
        tomcat.getConnector();
        Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("", new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(
                new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", new File("target/classes").getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

3. You can set breakpoints in IDE and debug as a normal Java application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's nice to see another way to do it!